# Java - Abstract Classes

Tags: java

If I declare class as abstract with no abstract methods declared in it, will it give a compilation error ?

Comment: What does your Java compiler do when you try that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not at all. An abstract class with no abstract methods can be used to signify a base class that is intended to be extended, but for which a concrete instance does not make sense.

Comment: +1: While my answer was a bit snarky, at least you took the time to also explain *why* :)

Answer (score 7):

Two minutes with your compiler would've told you the answer to that is "no".

Comment: Two minutes with his compiler may have made his homework assignment two minutes late.

Answer (score 0):

It will not give compiler error. but it dosen't make any sense by using abstract keyword.

Answer (score -1):

Abstract class declared with the keyword ‘abstract’, abstract class may or may not contain abstract method but if a Class has an abstract-method then the class is known as abstract class.

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be sub-classed,

When an abstract class is sub-classed, the subclass usually provides implementations for all of the abstract methods in its parent class.